# Why does my Discord.py Bot spam (and add numbers) in the chat?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot which job is simply adding, subtracting and suming up numbers. Everything works fine exept when you type "-1" (to subtract a number from the sum) it will spam "-1 was subtracted from your apples. You got (never ending numbers) apples." So it will say that It's subtracting -1 but at the same time it spams it and also adds numbers to it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} is connected to Discord!")

sum = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global sum
    if message.content.startswith("+1"):
        num = int(message.content.split(" ")[0])
        sum += num
        await message.channel.send(f"{num} was added to your apples, you got {sum} apples.")
    elif message.content.startswith("-1"):
        num = int(message.content.split(" ")[0])
        sum -= num
        await message.channel.send(f"{num} was subtracted from your apples, you got {sum} apples.")
    elif message.content.startswith("apples"):
        await message.channel.send(f"You have {sum} apples.")

client.run('token')``
`
```

Comment: Your bot is talking to itself.  It says something that starts with `-1` and then it responds to any message that starts with `-1` with another message that starts with `-1`.  Maybe it should pay attention to the author of the message?  Also, note that when you subtract a negative number, you get a positive result (just like you get a negative result when you add a negative number).

Comment: Unrelated, `sum` is a built-in function in Python (that's why it's syntax-highlighted in this post).  I suggest using a different variable name, maybe `num_apples`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Samwise pointed out, your bot is responding to itself. You need to add the following to your `on_message` function to prevent it triggering for itself. From the [quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) docs.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # rest of your on_message function
```